# What is the best visual tool for seeing what is taking up the most space on a mac?

Tags: mac, hard-drive, disk-space

Windows has great tools for visual usage of a disk, does mac have anything that is a simple visual tool of space usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several inlcuding

[Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/index.html)
[GrandPerspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net/)

I prefer a character based one

[OmniDiskSweeper](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnidisksweeper/)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few packages...

[Whatsize](http://www.whatsizemac.com/) - Shareware
[Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/) - Donationware
[Daisy Disk](http://www.daisydiskapp.com/) - Shareware

Overall, both Whatsize and Disk Inventory X are great packages...